# Custom handling of memory reads and writes in C

Tags: c, gcc, memory, malloc

I am working on writing my own `malloc` and using the `LD_PRELOAD` trick to use it. I need to be able to perform custom functionality for every memory access to the heap, both reads and writes (performance is not a concern, functionality is the goal).

For example, for some code like

```c
int x = A[5];
```

I would like to be able to trap the read from `(A + 5)` and instead of reading from that memory location, return my own custom value to store in `x`.

The ideas I have as of now are:

1. `mprotect` away, handling the resulting SIGSEGVs and doing what I need to in the handler. As far as I know, I can access the faulty address in `void *si_addr`, but I'm not sure how to distinguish between a read and a write - and even if I did manage to do so, I'm not sure how to handle writes since I wouldn't know the value to be written within the handler.
2. Tweak gcc to handle memory accesses specially. From what I have read, understanding gcc code takes a while, and unless its IR/abstract assembly conveniently isolates memory loads/stores, I'm not sure how practical this is.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how this can work natively without kernel support and *pervasive* modifications to the compiler's code generator.  I estimate the task to be extremely difficult.  It might be easier to implement a virtual machine supporting the wanted semantics, but this is still a huge job if you have to start from scratch.

Comment: If you aren't limited to LD_PRELOADing, you can also dynamically rewrite the code that will be executed, as valgrind's [memcheck](https://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) and Sun's dbx's [memory access checking](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5257/blahm/index.html) do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is via malloc ( you might want to own mmap, munmap, mprotect, sig(action, nal, etc) ... for full coverage ).   Yours return addresses which do not correspond to valid mappings, capture SIGBUS + SIGSEGV, interpret the siginfo structure to fixup your process, ...  But this is somewhat limited to operating on the heap, and a program can readily escape from it, and if you are trying to catch a misbehaving program, the program might corrupt your lookup tables.

For fuller coverage, you might want to take a look at *gvisor*, which is billed as a container runtime sandbox.   Its technology is closer to a debugger, as it takes full control over the target, capturing its faults, system calls, etc.. and manages its address space.  It would likely be minor surgery to adapt it to your needs.

In either situation, when you take a fault, you have to either install the memory and restart the program or emulate the instruction.  If you are dealing with a clean architecture like riscv or ARM, emulation isn’t too bad, but for an over-indulgent one like x86, you pretty much need to integrate qemu.  If you take the gvisor-like approach, you can install the page and set the single-step flag, then remove the page on the single-step trap, which is a bit less cumbersome.  There was a precursor to *dtrace*, called *atrace*, that used this approach to analyze cache and tlb access patterns.

Sounds like a fun project; I hope it goes well.